Finding orthonormal basis of eigenfunctions for integral operator
We consider the operator $K: L^2([0,1]) \rightarrow L^2([0,1])$, defined by
$$(Kf)(t) = \int_0^1 \cos(2 \pi (t-s)) f(s) ds.$$
As an exercise, I am asked to compute its eigenvalues and eigenfunctions. In particular, I am asked to find a orthonormal basis consisting of eigenfunctions (such a basis exists since $K$ is compact, self-adjoint and positive semi-definite).  I started with
$$ \int_0^1 \cos(2 \pi (t-s)) u(s) ds = \lambda u(t).$$
We notice that the LHS is twice differentiable, so $u$ is in particular twice differentiable, and we get
$$\lambda u''(t) = -4 \pi^2  \int_0^1 \cos(2 \pi (t-s)) u(s) ds = -4 \pi^2 \lambda u(t),$$
i.e. if $\lambda \neq 0$ we get the differential equation
$$ u'' + 4 \pi^2 u = 0,$$
which has solution
$$u(t) = A\sin(2 \pi t) + B \cos(2 \pi t).$$
Now when we plug our solution for $u$ back into $K$, one gets
$$ (Ku)(t) = \frac{1}{2} u(t),$$
so $u$ is an eigenfunction with eigenvalue $\frac{1}{2}$. Also, we want $u$ to be normalized, i.e.
$$1 = \int_0^1 ∣u(t)∣^2 dt = \frac{1}{2} \left(A^2 + B^2 \right).$$
So far so good. But now I'm unsure what to do next. For example, $u_1(t) = \sqrt{2} \sin(2 \pi t) $ or $u_2(t) = \sqrt{2} \cos(2 \pi t)$ are solutions, and they are also orthonormal, but how can we find a basis?
Another thing that bothers is that by the Spectral Theorem we should be able to write
$$K \varphi = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \lambda_n \langle \varphi , u_n\rangle u_n,$$
where the $\{u_n \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ are an orthonormal basis of eigenfunctions, and the $\lambda_n$ are the associated eigenvalues, that are real and non-negative, and in particular should decay, so $\lambda_n \rightarrow 0$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$. But we see that the only possible eigenvalues are $0$ and $1/2$, and since $\lambda_n \rightarrow 0$, this means there can only be finitely many $u_n$ for the eigenvalue $1/2$. This would imply that the set of functions
$$U := \{ A \sin(2 \pi t) + B \cos(2 \pi t) : A^2 + B^2 = 2\}$$
is generated by only a finite amount of functions. This seems false.

The functions $2^{-1/2}\cos(2\pi nt),$  $2^{-1/2}\sin (2\pi nt)$ for $n \ge 1$, and $1$ form a basis consisting of the eigenfunctions.

You can expand the $\cos(2\pi(t-s))$ and use Fourier series

@RyszardSzwarc So are there just 2 solutions for eigenvalue 1/2?

As suggested by @LPZ the operator is of the form $$ (K\varphi)(t)=\cos(2\pi t)\int\limits_0^1\cos(2\pi s)\varphi(s),ds+\sin(2\pi t)\int\limits_0^1\sin(2\pi s)\varphi(s),ds$$ So the operator is two dimensional. Its eigenvalues are $1/2$ and $0.$

Ah, now I see. Thanks

Observe that,
$$
u(t)=\frac{\cos(2\pi t) + \sin(2\pi t)}{2} 
$$
and
$$
u(t)=\frac{\cos(2\pi t) - \sin(2\pi t)}{2} 
$$
are solutions to the equation.  You can take it from there.

Why not $\cos(2\pi t)$ and $\sin(2\pi t)$ ?
